# reactJS/Axios and dealing with long response time with Streams maybe?

Tags: java, reactjs, rest, spring-boot, axios

I have Java spring-boot backend with some endpoints for data.

One of these is `POST` with few parameters using axios.
Problem here is that request takes very long time to fully be done and send from the server side. `POST` needs to be dissected and parameters forwarded inside the application and then calculate the response.

Im returning a `List<Object>` (needs to be sorted beforehand)

First part of the list will be ready in few seconds, but getting the whole list takes minutes or even tens of minutes, depending on parameters that were send.

So first problem is Axios throwing `network error` which i assume is because of very long response time. (It goes away when using shorter querys)
Second problem is application seems unresponsive for anyone but the developers.

**Is there a way to use some Java Stream kind of solution to send the first part of response while waiting for rest of it?
Or maybe some kind of pagination solution?**

I've been googeling for a while but havent yet hit any good solutions for this problem.

Here is part of controller for reference:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/contracts", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String Contracts(@RequestBody String req)  throws JsonProcessingException {

    //omitting parse JSON params from req string

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(DateRange.getDataForDateRange(param1, param2, param3));
}
```

I understand this is kind of broad question but understanding a way or tech behind doing this would be really beneficial for about everything i do :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soo finally got my answer.

Found my answer with java class called **DeferredResult**

I'm not sure why, but it seems you cant get *Any* answers to questions
harder than very basics and obvious stuff at SO anymore...

This is n:th question i answer myself after few days of research..